# Selectable textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a use case for a textbox but that has some default options e.g. if a user was asked to type their address but it would also be a select box so they could select their home address or work address.

Is there something out there like this? I have been googling but i cant see anything similar but i could be googling the wrong thing entirely.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want a *combo box* control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/AutoComplete)?

It has the functionality you are looking for plus the ability to automatically filter the user's options based on what the user is typing.